# how do I paste a picture from the clipboard into Mathematica and convert it to a list

Tags: graphics

I pasted an image from the clipboard into a Mathematica notebook.  When I try to perform imagedata on it, it says:
ImageData::imginv: Expecting an image or graphics instead of {1}.

So how do I make an image an image?

Comment: Pasting into an input cell and using `ImageData` on it works for me in 11.3 / macOS and has worked in every past version I can remember. You'd need to provide more information so people can understand what you are doing precisely.

Comment: In your case, it is saying that the input is not an `Image` or `Graphic` which begs the question "What is it?".  Try running `Head[ <picture>]`

Answer (score 3):

Pasting your image directly into `ImageData[your_image_here]` should work.  For example, I paste the image of the moon below into `ImageData[]` and it returns a list of pixel values.  What does `ImageType[]` return when you paste your image into it?  Can you upload your image to help others diagnose the problem?

`ImageData[`[image: Moon]`]`

[image: Pixel Data]